# What store and location is my certificate installed in?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, certificate

I have a Console Application which will access certificate information (in order to pass it through to a Web Service).  The certificate I need to access is installed on a server, accessible through IIS.

Certificates are fairly new for us as we have a lot of internal applications, and not so much external applications.

To retrieve certificate information , I am creating a new instance of a `X509Store` object, and then using that store to call the Find method to populate a `X509CertificateCollection` object.  From there, I can retrieve the information necessary about the certificate.

I created a dummy certificate on my `localmachine` and verified that my `.NET` code is working as expected.  Now I'm updating that code, to play nicely with the server(s) I will be deploying the application to.

---

1. Will executing the application from a share directory (to the server) from  my local machine act the same executing the application directly on the server?

   Unfortunately, I do not have access directly to the server to execute the application myself, but will be deploying the application to the server through this shared directory.
2. How do I tell what `StoreName` and `StoreLocation` to use when creating a new instance of a `X509Store`?

   `X509Store certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName, StoreLocation);`

   I assume the `StoreLocation` parameter would be set to `StoreLocation.LocalMachine`.  I am not sure what the `StoreName` to use would be; I'm not sure the server admin would know if I gave him a list of the eligible parameter values for that enumerator.

Comment: IIS web site bindings can only use certificates installed in the computer account's Personal Store, whose name is "MY" if you check Microsoft documentation. But what's the purpose of your console app? If it talks to an IIS web site via HTTPS, it should query the certificate from the server response, not reading from the store.

Comment: @LexLi Our console app is sending data through a third-party web service.  The purpose of retrieving the certificate information is so that we can digitally sign the SOAP Request.  Is there a different way this should be accomplished?

Comment: It would be difficult to talk further if you know nothing about the purposes of a certificate. The certificates installed for IIS are generally for server authentication only while the certificates to digitally sign something require another purpose. Usually you cannot misuse a certificate.